# React-Native: Prevent FlatList to render anything outside viewport

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a FlatList which renders a productInformation item, which you can scroll through (so you horizontally scroll through the products).
The Info items have a lot of pictures and since Android 9 there is a severe performance problem with lots of images in ScrollViews. So I want the FlatList to only render the visible item and unmount and not cache the previous shown items.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: I thought flatlist doesnt render elements that are not currently in the view?

Comment: I thought so too, but the images are still in the cache, because they are immediately visible. So there is no reload. And I want to achieve a hard reload of the contents.

Comment: maybe this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49015211/does-load-large-amount-of-images-in-flatlist-hurt-performance-and-how-to-avoid-i?rq=1

Comment: Thx, I'll look into this.

Comment: But I actually think that there is a deeper problem here. In my understanding, there should be a control mechanism, whether or not RNs FlatList should cache the images that are not visible, so the app doesn't run into memory problems.